# How to display properly the template's elements of my Knockout app?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've started to work with Knockout.js and wanted to write some simple component, but the code I've written didn't display template's elements. I'm only seeing the text inside "h1" tag.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Component</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Counter starting at 1:</h1>
        <counter params="initialCount: 1"></counter>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function viewModel(params) {
                const self = this;
                self.count = ko.observable(params.initialCount);
                self.increment = () => self.count(self.count() + 1);
            }
            const template = 
            `<div>
                <span data-bind="text: count"></span>
                <button type="button" data-bind="click: increment">
                        Increment
                </button>
            </div>`;
            ko.components.register('counter', { viewModel, template });
        </script>       

    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `ko.applyBindings();` at the end of your script.